# Why the space of Lipschitz functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the uniform norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions, sequence-of-function

is not a Banach space ?

We have to find a Cauchy sequence of Lipschitz functions $(f_n)_{n>0}$ such that this sequence does not converge to a Lipschitz function $f$ (for the norm $\vert \vert g \vert \vert_{\infty} = \sup_{t\in[0,1]} \vert g(t) \vert$ with $g$ a Lipschitz function).

How to build such a sequence ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can approximate every continuous function by polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea: pick a continuous function that's not Lipschitz, uniformly approximate it by Lipschitz functions. For instance if the function is only non-Lipschitz because of bad behavior near one point, just flatten it out near that point and leave it be everywhere else.

With that in mind, you can look at $f_n(x)=\left ( \max \{ 1/n,x \} \right )^{1/2}$, which converges uniformly to $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: For $n=2$ and for all $x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$ we have $f_2(x)=x^{1/2}$ which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: @Maman $x^{1/2}$ restricted to $[1/2,1]$ is indeed Lipschitz. The whole idea is that $\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$ but it is Lipschitz on $[\varepsilon,1]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: Ok that's clearer !

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}\sin(x^2) \text{ if } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\leq x \leq 1, \\
0 \text{ if } 0\leq x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}.
\end{cases}$

These are Lipschitz and you can check that they converge uniformly to
$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}\sin(x^2) \text{ if } 0< x \leq 1, \\
0 \text{ if } x=0.
\end{cases}$, but $f$ is not Lipschitz since $f'(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.